# Nested list alignment issues

Tags: html, css

I have a dropdown menu (full-width) on my dropdown, I have a nested list and I want each column to have equal height and width. I tried to add a container inside each column and put display: table-cell; but it seemed my code isn't working at all. can ya'll help me with this?

```
                    <div class="column">
                            <div class="col-container">
                                <ul id="sub-list">
                                    <li class="sub-list-item">
                                        <a class="sub-list-title">창업 프로세스</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nested-child">
                                        <ul class="sub-sub-list">
                                            <li class="item"><a class="sub-sub-title">경진대회정보</a></li>
                                            <li class="item"><a class="sub-sub-title">명예의 전당</a></li>
                                        </ul>   
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="sub-list-item">
                                        <a class="sub-list-title">행사 네트워크</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

snippet from style.scss

```
.column{
   float: left;
   margin: 0;
   display: table;
    .col-container{
    display: table-cell;
    background: yellow;
    padding: 21px;
    }
 }
```

I'll provide a photo of what the output should be like.
[image: This should be the output of the code]

This is made using nested UL. how do we achieve this one?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the flex-basis value to adjust the number of columns you want to dislplay, hope you have got the solution looking for.

[Refer flexbox:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)

```css
ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.list-item-main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.list-item-main>.list-item {
  list-style: none;
  flex-basis: 33%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px;
}

.list-item-main>.list-item .nested-ul>li {
  list-style: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.list-item-main .list-item-head {
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-container">
  <ul class="list-item-main">
    <li class="list-item">
      <a>Single List item</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      <ul class="nested-ul">
        <li class="list-item-head">nested list 1 item</li>
        <li class="list-item">nested list 1 item</li>
        <li class="list-item">nested list 1 item</li>
        <li class="list-item">nested list 1 item</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      <ul class="nested-ul">
        <li class="list-item-head">nested list 2 item</li>
        <li class="list-item">nested list 2 item</li>
        <li class="list-item">nested list 2 item</li>
        <li class="list-item">nested list 2 item</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      <ul class="nested-ul">
        <li class="list-item-head">nested list 3 item</li>
        <li class="list-item">nested list 3 item</li>
        <li class="list-item">nested list 3 item</li>
        <li class="list-item">nested list 3 item</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      <ul class="nested-ul">
        <li class="list-item-head">nested list 4 item</li>
        <li class="list-item">nested list 4 item</li>
        <li class="list-item">nested list 4 item</li>
        <li class="list-item">nested list 4 item</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```